# Error al usar $this cuando no está en el contexto del objeto

Tags: php, mvc, pdo

Hola gente de esta comunidad, quisiera que me ayuden porfavor, estoy aprendiendo MVC PHP PDO, cree un login de usuario de la clase usuario, el cual funciona y me redireciona a una pagina llamada save.php, el asunto es que necesito que en la pagina save.php me muestre un listado de alumnos de la tabla alumno, pero no puedo utilizar el método que tengo en esa clase y me arroja el sgte error: Error al usar $this cuando no está en el contexto del objeto, no se donde se encuentra el error o que me falta, dejo imágenes para que se entienda mejor, de ante mano, muchas gracias...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor agrega el código involucrado en tu pregunta, pues con una imagen no es sufieciente

Comment: `$this` se usa cuando estás dentro de la clase. Cuando estás fuera de ella, sólo puedes acceder a los métodos y propiedades públicas de la misma usando la instancia que has creado. Por ejemplo aquí estás fuera de la clase: `$tuInstancia=new TuClase();` Ahora para llamar a un método, desde ahí tienes que hacer: `$tuInstancia->unMetodoPublico();` si ahí intentas algo como `$this->unMetodoPublico();` te dará el error mencionado. De todos modos, por favor, pon el código que estás usando para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: esta es la clase alumnoModel:                                                                           <?php
class alumnoModel{
    public $CNXal;
    
    public $id_alumno;
    public $nombre;
    public $apellido;
    public $fecha_nacimiento;
    
    public function __construct() {
        try {
            //Accedemos a la conexion.
            $this->CNXal = Conexion::conectar();
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            die($exc->getMessage());
        }
    }   
}

Comment: el index:         <?php
include_once 'Controller/usuarioController.php';
include_once 'Config/conexion.php';

$usuarioController = new usuarioController();

if (!isset($_REQUEST['c'])) {
    $usuarioController->index();     
}else{   
    $action = $_REQUEST['c'];
    
    call_user_func(array($usuarioController,$action));     
}
 
?>

Comment: donde me arroja el error: 
                       
                        <?php foreach ($this->valor->listar() as $k):?>
      
                            <td><?php echo $k->id_alumno; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $k->nombre; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $k->apellido; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $k->fecha_nacimiento; ?></td>
               
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Acá dejo las imagenes que faltan, espero que se entienda algo y tengan piedad, soy nuevo XD..[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Todo el código publicado es de tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

usuarioController, lugar donde se encuentra el login de inicio de sesión.[[image: introducir la d[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

clase UsuarioModel
 donde se encuentran los metodo que he creado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

clase alumnoControlador, esta pertenece a otra tabla de la base de datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]